# Как сделать код для "Shift" в апплете "клавиатура"?

Tags: java, button, applet

В курсовой мне была поставлена задача сделать апплет-клавиатуру.
До этого с апплетами особо дела не имел. Почитал различные статьи.
Вообщем есть код, работающий корректно. Коды для кнопок писал сам. Проблема состоит в том, что не могу придумать код для "Shift". В интернете нашел методы позволяющие менять регистр, но они не совсем подходят мне. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как действовать. Если Вас не затруднит, то помогите с кодом, буду признателен.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Keyboard extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
String row1[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","Backspace"};
String row2[] = {"q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","Enter"};
String row3[] = {"a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l",":","Shift"};
String row4[] = {"z","x","c","v","b","n","m",",",".","?","Spacebar"};
JButton first[];
JButton second[];
JButton third[];
JButton fourth[];
JTextArea ta;
boolean shiftPressed = false;

public void init(){
  ta = new JTextArea();
  ta.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); 
  JLabel l = new JLabel("Enter your message here:" );
  l.setFont(new Font("TimesNewRoman",Font.BOLD,14));
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  JPanel jpNorth = new JPanel();
  JPanel jpCenter = new JPanel();
  JPanel jpButtons = new JPanel();

  add(jpNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(jpCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(jpButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  jpNorth.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  jpNorth.add(l, BorderLayout.WEST);
  jpNorth.add(l, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  jpCenter.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  jpCenter.add(ta, BorderLayout.WEST);
  jpCenter.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  jpButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

   first = new JButton[row1.length];
   JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, row1.length));
   for(int i = 0; i < row1.length; i++) 
   {
    JButton bt = new JButton(row1[i]);
    bt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    first[i] = bt;
    p.add(first[i]);
   }
   jpButtons.add(p);

   second = new JButton[row2.length];
   p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, row2.length));
   for(int i = 0; i < row2.length; i++) 
   {
    second[i] = new JButton(row2[i]);
    p.add(second[i]);
   }
   jpButtons.add(p);

   third = new JButton[row3.length];
   p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, row3.length));
   for(int i = 0; i < row3.length; i++)
   {
    third[i] = new JButton(row3[i]);
    p.add(third[i]);
   }
   jpButtons.add(p);

   fourth = new JButton[row4.length];
   p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, row4.length));
   for(int i = 0; i < row4.length; ++i)
   {
    fourth[i] = new JButton(row4[i]);
    p.add(fourth[i]);
   }
   jpButtons.add(p);

   for(JButton bt : first)
       bt.addActionListener(this); 
   for(JButton bt : second)
       bt.addActionListener(this); 
   for(JButton bt : third)
       bt.addActionListener(this); 
   for(JButton bt : fourth)
       bt.addActionListener(this); 
}            
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
      String ac = ae.getActionCommand();
      String text;
      switch (ac) {
          case "Enter":
              ta.setText(ta.getText()+"\n");
              break;
          case "Spacebar":
              ta.setText(ta.getText()+" ");
              break;
          case "Backspace":
              text = ta.getText();
              ta.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
              break;
          case "Shift":
              shiftPressed = true;
              break;
          default:
              register();
              break;
      }  
} 

private String register() {
    if (shiftPressed == true) {
        row1[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","Backspace"};
        row2[] = {"Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","Enter"};
        row3[] = {"A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L",":","Shift"};
        row4[] = {"Z","X","C","V","B","N","M",",",".","?","Spacebar"};
        shiftPressed = false;
    } else {
        row1[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","Backspace"};
        row2[] = {"q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","Enter"};
        row3[] = {"a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l",":","Shift"};
        row4[] = {"z","x","c","v","b","n","m",",",".","?","Spacebar"};
    }
    return ta.setText(ta.getText() + String.valueOf(ac));
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявить переменную переключатель:

```
private boolean shiftPressed = false;
```

А в switch'е как-то так:

```
switch (ac) {
case "Enter":
    ta.setText(ta.getText() + "\n");
    break;
case "Spacebar":
    ta.setText(ta.getText() + " ");
    break;
case "Backspace":
    text = ta.getText();
    ta.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
    break;
case "Shift":
    shiftPressed = (shiftPressed) ? false : true;
    break;
default:
    text = String.valueOf(ac);
    text = (shiftPressed) ? text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();
    ta.setText(ta.getText() + text);
    break;
}
```

Я думаю лучше так, нежели использовать ваш метод `register`.
У вас row(1-4) три раза в итоге повторяется.

Comment: премного вам благодарен. Раз уж Вы мне помогли, могу ли просить Вас объяснить некие моменты?

Comment: @MuscledBoy, спрашивайте. Я с java не работал почти, но попытаюсь помочь

Comment: 1) Я использовал часть кода                                                     **for(JButton bt : first)
    bt.addActionListener(this);** для добавления интерфейса, а как поточнее рассшифровать **for**?

Comment: 2) Я догадываюсь о том что делают  строчки  ** shiftPressed = (shiftPressed) ? false : true;** и **text = (shiftPressed) ? text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();**   . в первом случае кнопка имеетесли был **false** - будет **true** при нажатии  и во второй, мы меняем шрифты (к стати, я думал что эти методы меняют регистр всей строки, но только введенной, а выходит их также можно использовать дле смены регистра будещего введенного символа???? )

Comment: и как во втором пункте используються ? : как условия действий происходящих?

Comment: @MuscledBoy, ? это тернарный оператор. Часто используется для замены выражений if...esle.
Т.е в нашем случае будет так: переменная `shiftPressed = (условие) ? значение если условие истинно : значение если условие ложно`.
Мы могли бы использовать `if...else`. Тогда бы код выглядел так:
  `if (shiftPressed) {
   text.toUpperCase();
  } else {
   text.toLowerCase();
  }`
Ну и его использование в нашем случае делает код читабельнее.

Comment: @MuscledBoy, мы используем цикл foreach. Это другая форма цикла for. Применима к массивам, классам реализующим итерфес `Iterable`. 
`for(тип перменной итерационная переменная : коллекция)`.
Тип переменной - тип итерационной переменной которая будет последовательно принимать значения из коллекции. Сам цикл выполняется по коллекции.
Вы создавали кнопки в цикле и помещали их в first, second, third, fourth. Вот и получается, что вы перебираете их.
Из коллекции `first` берем элемент и помещаем его в итерационную переменную `bt`. А далее на `bt` вешаете слушателя.
Как-то так

Comment: @MuscledBoy "к стати, я думал что эти методы меняют регистр всей строки, но только введенной, а выходит их также можно использовать дле смены регистра будещего введенного символа???? ) "
Пропустил. Зависит от того как вы используете их. У вас же после нажатия кнопки символы(одно нажатие - один символ) попадают в switch и далее идут в default секцию(если они не имеют спец значения, которые вы в том же switch'e обозначили - shift, enter, итп) и тут уже меняется их регистр в зависимости от состояния shift'a

Comment: спасибо за Ваше внимание. Все довольно понятно)

Answer (score 1):

в классе `Keyboard` хранишь состояние шифта (булево нажат/отжат),
создаешь метод в котором добавляешь символы в `ta` с учетом состояния шифта
и этот метод вызываешь в `default:`

Comment: ну а чтобы это все было ThreadSafe то нужно состояние шифта хранить в Atomic

Comment: не пойму, что Вы имеете в виду: **"чтобы это все было ThreadSafe то нужно состояние шифта хранить в Atomic"**? Я просто с такими вещами не сталкивался. Мгли бы Вы объяснить что это.

Comment: видите ли в потоках я не силен, и знаю о нихочень мало

Comment: подкорректируйте, если можно так сказать мой код, а то я вообще уже ничего не понимаю. Буду вам благодарен.